# What's the most efficient method for moving and transcoding HD video from my Tivo to iTunes on OS X while preserving quality?

Tags: macos, tivo

I've got a Tivo with some HD recordings on it. I'd like to move those files over to my Mac and add them into iTunes.  I'd like the move and transcoding to be as painless as possible, and I'd like to preserve the quality of the original HD recording.

I've got a network connection to the Tivo and can move the files over but the real problem seems to be transcoding.  I tried using MEncoder to transcode to H.264 but the quality really suffered. I was doing the conversion at 10mbps so I'm not sure why the quality was so bad, lots of artifacting, etc.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but I think you can do this with Quicktime Pro, which is about $35.

Answer (score 0):

I'd give handbrake a shot.  It has worked great for most of what I've thrown at it.  You may have to tweak settings, but the defaults should be a good starting point.  The big thing to check is how it handles the audio stream.  I've noticed that some of the defaults want to convert everything to stereo.  It's easy enough to change, just check.